# When tabbing out of control, enable disabled control that follows it, so that focus will go to that control, and not skip it?

Tags: c#, winforms

Before leaving a textbox due to the user hitting the Tab key, I want to enable a control that follows it tabstop-wise, so that it becomes the focused control.

Instead it seems Winforms has already decided where focus will go so it skips the control.

I have tried using the `Validating` and `Validated` events to enable the control that follows, but it seems this too is too late, even though I know that if validation indicates failure, focus will not leave the control so clearly tab behavior can be affected at validation time.

So, example specific scenario (code follows):

1. 3 controls, textbox + checkbox + textbox
2. Checkbox is disabled, focus is currently in the first textbox
3. As part of leaving the first textbox, I want to validate the contents of it, and if OK, I would like to enable the checkbox
4. As such, if the user is in the first textbox, fills it with valid data, and hits Tab, focus should now be on the checkbox, and not on the second textbox.

Observed behavior is that focus moves to the second textbox, skipping the checkbox, and the checkbox is enabled, possibly not in that order (ie. I'm describing the observed end results, not necessarily the order things happen in).

Is it possible to get what I want?

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates the problem

```
void Main()
{
    var fm = new Form();

    var e1 = new TextBox();
    e1.Location = new Point(8, 8);
    e1.CausesValidation = true;
    e1.TabIndex = 0;
    e1.TabStop = true;

    var chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Text = "Checkbox";
    chk.Location = new Point(8, e1.Bottom + 8);
    chk.Enabled = false;
    chk.TabIndex = 1;
    chk.TabStop = true;

    var e2 = new TextBox();
    e2.Location = new Point(8, chk.Bottom + 8);
    e2.TabIndex = 2;
    e2.TabStop = true;

    fm.Controls.Add(e1);
    fm.Controls.Add(chk);
    fm.Controls.Add(e2);

    e1.Validating += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e1 validating");
        chk.Enabled = true;
    };

    e1.Validated += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e1 validated");
        chk.Enabled = true;
    };

    chk.Enter += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("chk entered");
    e2.Enter += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("e2 entered");

    fm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have to process entire Tab key sequence yourselves.

Comment: Which event do you use to catch the Tab key? You may set e.handled=true and set the focus in code.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off validating the input in the `TextChanged` event, such as:

```
e1.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    chk.Enabled = (e1.Text.Length > 2);
};
```

The MSDN docs for the [`Control.Validating` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) include this warning:

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding. For more information, see the WM_KILLFOCUS topic in the "Keyboard Input Reference" section, and the "Message Deadlocks" section of the "About Messages and Message Queues" topic in the MSDN library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

I don't remember the specific order that Windows uses processing messages, but I suspect that the message enabling the `chk` checkbox gets sent **after** Windows processes the tab keypress. Doing your validation in `TextChanged` events means you don't have to worry about this weird race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a hack. but works..

```
e1.Leave += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e1 Leave");
        chk.Enabled = true;
        fm.SelectNextControl( e1,true,true,true,true);
    };
```